# FLOW: how to make Flow work with callback for Array.prototype.find()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype, flow-typed

Guys I'm new to Flow.

I have this code

```
type importItem = {
  name: string,
  groupRank: number,
  rank: number,
  node: Object,
};
function findTargetImportItem(importedItems: Array<importItem>, outOfOrderItem: importItem) : importItem {

return importedItems.find((importedItem: importItem) => importedItem.rank > outOfOrderItem.rank);}
```

I got this error

```
Cannot return importedItems.find(...) because undefined [1] is incompatible with importItem [2].

     src/rules/import-order.js
 [2]  74│ function findTargetImportItem(importedItems: Array<importItem>, outOfOrderItem: importItem) : importItem {
      75│   /**
      76│      * Return the import where the unordered imports will be moving towards
      77│      */
      78│   return importedItems.find((importedItem: importItem) => importedItem.rank > outOfOrderItem.rank);
      79│ }
      80│
      81│ function hasTrailingSpace(sourceCode, node) {

     /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_21840530/core.js
 [1] 244│     find(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: Array<T>) => any, thisArg?: any): T | void;
```

I don't know how to make Flow know that the stuff returned by the find helper function is an importItem type.

Can you guys help me with this

Answer (score 6):

The flow compiler is correct. It knows that the value returned by `find()` *can* be `undefined`.

If none of the items in the array satisfy the condition in the callback you've passed, the return value will be `undefined`. Either change your return type for `findTargetImportItem()` to `void | importItem` or assign the return value of `find()` to a temporary variable and return some default value of type `importItem` if the temporary variable is `undefined`.

#### Solution 1

```
function findTargetImportItem(importedItems: Array<importItem>, outOfOrderItem: importItem) : void | importItem {
  /**
    * Return the import where the unordered imports will be moving towards
    */
  return importedItems.find((importedItem: importItem) => importedItem.rank > outOfOrderItem.rank);
}
```

#### Solution 2

```
const defaultImportItem: importItem = ...;

function findTargetImportItem(importedItems: Array<importItem>, outOfOrderItem: importItem) : importItem {
  /**
    * Return the import where the unordered imports will be moving towards
    */
  const importedItem = importedItems.find((importedItem: importItem) => importedItem.rank > outOfOrderItem.rank);

  return importedItem === undefined
    ? defaultImportItem
    : importedItem;
}
```

Comment: Or throw an exception explicitly about the missing value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However I tried your first solution I got this error.        `Cannot use undefined as a type because undefined is a value. To get the type of a value use typeof.` .

Comment: @ZhenghaoHe try `void`. Sorry I didn't know flow doesn't allow `undefined` as a type (since TypeScript _does_).

Comment: Thanks! @PatrickRoberts . Also can I ask, is it that for all JS files where flow type is used. We need to strip away Flow types using some compilers like Babel for it to be able to work properly, so that those type annotations only appear during the development process. Does this mean that we never know how those type annotations are used for JS projects e.g. ESLint plugins because the code we can see has already been stripped out?

Comment: @ZhenghaoHe I don't understand your question, but what I can say is that the type enforcement is strictly done at compile time (e.g. the babel transpilation step). The runtime behavior is completely unaffected by type annotations, but during development they help identify a large class of programmer errors that static analysis tools like ESLint would otherwise overlook.

Comment: @loganfsmyth while that is a valid solution, I would consider that to be code-smell depending on the situation, as that would potentially qualify as a [vexing exception](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) pattern.

Comment: Totally agree that it 100% depends on whether the item not being found would qualify as "boneheaded" or "fatal" in that article's terms.